# How can I check if my data through VPS is using iodine (DNS tunnel)?

Tags: linux, port-forwarding, tunnel, vps, iodine

Using `Wireshark` there are so many calls that I cannot truly find anything. But, when I browse internet through Firefox, on `Wireshark` it says the protocol was DNS. But, while using the VPS as a proxy I can't see any any DNS request being made. So is there any way to make DNS calls from my VPS while using it as a proxy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Istiak and welcome to Superuser! Could you please [edit] your question to include what your setup is? How are you proxying through the VPS? What settings are you using? Where did you set them? How do you monitor DNS requests? What have you looked into so far?